# why list and string are behaving differently while checking equality in the below case

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why is the equality behaving differently? In case of list it's giving false but in case of string it's giving true  and in the last case it's strangely False

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1[:]
print(id(list1))
print(id(list2))
print(list1 is list2)
print(id(list1) == id(list2))
```

140271225865864 
140271225867080 
False 
False

```
list3="hello"
list4=list3[:]
print(id(list3))
print(id(list4))
print(list3 is list4)
```

140271226135360 
140271226135360 
True

```
list5="hello"
list6 = ''.join(c for c in list5) 
print(list5 is list6)
```

False

Comment: Since strings are immutable, it does not matter to return the same object for shallow copy, it saves the time to make a real copy. For lists though, it does matter as they are mutable.

Comment: Further, because of mutability, `list1[:]` *must* create a new list. Since a `str` is immutable, `list3[:]` *can* return the same `str`, but I don't know that there is anything saying it *must*.

Comment: Just a successor doubt on this .. list4 = ''.join(c for c in list3) print(list4 is list3) .. then why this gives False as output , as this also creates the same string @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of immutable. String being the lucky one that python enforces the same copy of 'hello' is used wherever in the entire code. So

```
s='hello'
#many lines of code
t='hello'
id(t)==id(s)
```

tuple being unlucky that

```
s=(1,2)
#many lines of code
t=(1,2)
id(t)!=id(s)
#but you do have
hash(t)==hash(s)
```

List is mutable so it is guaranteed that

```
s=[1,2]
#many lines of code
t=[1,2]
id(t)!=id(s)
#You cannot run hash on mutables
hash(t)==hash(s) #error
```

Comment: Just a successor doubt on this .. list4 = ''.join(c for c in list3)     print(list4 is list3)  .. then why this gives False as output ,  as this also creates the same string

Comment: Strictly speaking, whether `s` and `t` refer to the same string object is an implementation detail. This is a bit different than the OP's question, where one of the strings is the result of a string operation, not a repetition of the same string literal.

Comment: I think if they don't refer to the same object there is no match on id() which OP asked

Comment: Just a successor doubt on this .. list4 = ''.join(c for c in list3) print(list4 is list3) .. then why this gives False as output , as this also creates the same string @BingWang

Comment: @Kumar you are right. sorry never realize this